# use sencha touch with eclipse indigo

Tags: mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

how can i use EXT JS mobile with eclipse to create android apps?  I've downloaded   sencha-touch-2.3.1 and eclipse indigo and i've integrated android plugin in it. Now I've created a new android projet and i didn't know how to use sencha touch. can you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencha Touch can be used to build native applictions. The Sencha Team suggests using phonegap/cordova for doing so; they implemented a command line tool that supports you in this process without using eclipse.
[This is the tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/blog/leveraging-phonegap-within-sencha-touch) that can help you.
There is even a [video tutorial](http://vimeo.com/76568053) of 45minutes